# How does derived class override base's class interface method

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I'm trying to figure out how does method overriding works in C# and next peace of code really confuced me (.NET 5 and C# 9.0):

```
    interface IPayable
    {
        public int Pay();
    }

    class Human : IPayable
    {
        int IPayable.Pay()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    class Debtor : Human
    {
        int Pay()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**Question**

How does `Debtor.Pay()` method override base's class implementation of interface without any warning about hiding base's class functionality or without explicit `virtual or abstract` specification in base class method ?

**Note**

I know that if I write `Human.Pay()` method as `virtual or abstract`  I will be able to `override` it explicitly, but the main point of my question is to find out how this code snippet implicitly works.

Comment: _"How does Debtor.Pay() method override base's class implementation"_ - **it doesn't**.

Comment: @Dai, that means that it's normal behavior and any derived class can implement interface's methods of base class without any additional specifications?

Comment: Just to clarify: does your  `interface` actually have `public int Pay();` (i.e. with an explicit `public` keyword but without any method body?) - or is it just `int Pay();` ?

Comment: FWIW, the code you've posted _doesn't compile_ in VS2022 (with C# 10) because `Debtor.Pay` is `private`. Please post a full example that I can copy-and-paste-and-run that reproduces the behaviour you're describing.

Comment: "any derived class can implement interface's methods of base class" No, `Debtor.Pay` doesn't implement `IPayable.Pay`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, it was my unawareness about how thing works with interfaces and derived classes.

I wrote next lines:

```
            var human = new Human();
            var debtor = new Debtor();

            Console.WriteLine(((IPayable)human).Pay());
            Console.WriteLine(((IPayable)debtor).Pay());

           //Output: 1
           //        1
```

That means that if I explicitly implements interfaces method like this `IPayable.Pay()`, inside derived class, roughly speaking, will exist two methods - `base.IPayable.Pay` and `this.Pay`. Thus program considers it like two different methods and doesn't warn about it.

But if I change a little code like this:

```
    interface IPayable
    {
        public int Pay();
    }

    class Human : IPayable
    {
        public int Pay()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    class Debtor : Human
    {
        int Pay()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I'll get a warning:

`Warning    CS0108  'Debtor.Pay()' hides inherited member 'Human.Pay()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`